# Colored output in less when tailing a logfile

Tags: sed, logs, colors, less

I am in dire need of a way to color my less output while reading a file that is constantly being appended.

The file in questions is a Resin servlet container log.

My current "implementation" of the color scheme works using `tail -F` and `sed` for editing in colors around keywords. I have four words to color: `INFO, WARN, ERROR, DEBUG`, one of which occurs once per line.

I have tried using the `LESSOPEN`environment variable, but I can't seem to keep reading the log. The file is not tailed once it has been open.

I have very little control over the server, and cannot really install anything other than my own scripts in my home folder, so no packages. The server in question is a RHEL 6.4.

The problem is that `less` does not keep reading the file.
Is there a way to tail the log continuously using the `LESSOPEN`environment variable, or do I need some more complex tools?

Comment: Is the file already coloured using ANSI escape sequences or do you need to add the colours as well?

Comment: You haven't stated your exact problem. What is not working? Is `less` not getting new output, is it stripping the colors, what?

Comment: Colors are working, less is not tailing, it just reads what the file looks like when it's first opened.

Comment: have a look at multitail

Comment: Shift-f does not tail it. `multitail` is not an option, can't install anything on the server.

Comment: @Jes try pressing SHIFT+G when in less to have it grab new data and jump to the end

Comment: The problem is that CTRL+C closes the pipe. The solution is to use a temporary file to tail the colored log into, then less that file. Found a similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/186793/less-tail-mode-pipes

Comment: Who pressed `ctrl+c`? That is not in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the pipes on linux. <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> closes the pipe and `less` cannot reopen the pipe.

The solution I found viable was to redirect the colored log to a file, then read that file with `less`. A file *can* be tailed after a `CTRL-c`, and I therefore just do the following:

```
tail -F -c +1 | colorize > /tmp/logfilename &
less -Sr /tmp/logfilename
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I see two questions here:

- How do I color output in less
- How do I make less behave like tail -f

I can't answer the first one, though `LESSOPEN` seems like a good avenue. The second one is easy: start less as `less +F` or hit <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> if less is already running.

Answer (score 1):

You could run `tail -f` [in an Emacs shell buffer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70419/horizontal-scrolling-in-terminal/70572#70572), and let Emacs do the coloring.

[Hi Lock](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Highlight-Interactively.html) lets you quickly highlight words matching a regexp. There's a crude way to save highlighting patterns in a file, but it won't be convenient when the file is actually the output of a command. You're probably better off writing a simple [major mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Major-Modes.html#Major-Modes) with [font lock](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Font-Lock-Mode.html#Font-Lock-Mode) [keywords](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FontLockKeywords).

Answer (score 0):

I use vim to simulate colored `less`. It has a `less` macro and uses the Vim color scheme.

I added this to my bashrc:

```
alias cless='/usr/share/vim/vim73/macros/less.sh'
```

For the tailing/following, you will need some Vim plugin that allows for following. Perhaps try the [Tail Bundle](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1714) plugin.